# hard disk virtual machine Ubuntu enlarge

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed a virtual machine Ubuntu on VirtualBox. Unfortunately, the hard disk is only 10 GB. Is there a way to increase the size of my hard disk?

Comment: Did you consider installing Ubuntu or [Debian](https://debian.org/) directly on your laptop or desktop?

Comment: yo have to use resize command, here an example https://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/

Comment: You could probably add a new virtual disk in virtualbox and mount it in your VM.